# Simplest way to output a simple MIDI file?

Tags: java, midi

I have a few notes each with a midi number, duration, and velocity.

I am currently using Synthesizer to play out the notes:

```
Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synthesizer.open();

MidiChannel[] channels = synthesizer.getChannels();

for(Note n: song)
{
    n.playNote(channels[0]);
}

synthesizer.close();
```

**Note.playNote()**

```
public void playNote(MidiChannel c) throws InterruptedException
{
    if (type == 'n')
    c.noteOn(noteNumber, 60);
    Thread.sleep(getLength());
    if (type == 'n')
    c.noteOff(noteNumber);
}
```

However, now I would like to save this to a midi file. What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: http://www.automatic-pilot.com/midifile.html 
This can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple procedure is essentially as follows:

- create a Sequence object;
- create one or more tracks (sequence.createTrack())
- for each note, create relevant MidiMessages representing note on and note off messages and add them to the track
- call MidiSystem.write() to write the populated Sequence to a file.